# No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.internal.core.GradleVariantConfiguration

Tags: android, gradle

I have a problem when using Android Studio 3. when using variant debug run well. Anyone can help?

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0' 
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip
```

Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.android.build.gradle.internal.core.GradleVariantConfiguration.getFlatPackageAndroidLibraries() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
        at com.guardsquare.dexguard.cU.getProguardFiles(DexGuard7.3.11:1337)
        at com.guardsquare.dexguard.dl.doCall(DexGuard7.3.11:262)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:722)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:695)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)

I think this problem because gradle cannot access dexguard file. So, we wait for dexguard fixed it.

Comment: facing same issue using dexguard 8.0

Comment: Need to email them I think

Comment: @AbdulSaleem just use gradlew 8.1.00 and android studio 3.1.0 fix that issue

Comment: I can't find android studio 3.1.0 on https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html. DexGuard support team told to download new DexGuard version from account

Comment: i am sorry 3.0.1 i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Once I upgraded Android Studio 3.1, I had the same issue. I download the latest Dexguard 8.2.05 and it solved this problem.

I think that if you are running Android Studio 3 and you should upgrade Dexguard to 8.2. This combination solved my issue.

Comment: this basically incompatible version of gradle, that dexguard does not handle yet at that moment. but, now already fixed